# How do I access parameters in ReflectionFunction that have been passed using use() in closure

Tags: php

Recently I've been facing the issue to access the parameters via a ReflectionFunction that have been passed via the `use()` construct to a closure.

Example:

```
$var = 'test';
$var2 = 'test2';
$func = function()use($var,$var2) {
    echo $var;
};

$ref = new ReflectionFunction($func);
// Access the parameters here
```

How would I go on to solve this problem?

Comment: How is my question "Unclear what im asking"? Feel free to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by accessing `$ref->getStaticVariables()`.

Example:

```
<?php


$var = 'test';
$var2 = 'test2';
$func = function()use($var,$var2) {
    echo $var;
};

$ref = new ReflectionFunction($func);
var_dump($ref->getStaticVariables());
```

Output:

> array(2) {
>     ["var"]=>
>     string(4) "test"
>     ["var2"]=>
>     string(5) "test2"
>   }

Working testcase: https://3v4l.org/hDl07

Reference `getStaticVariables()`: http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionfunctionabstract.getstaticvariables.php

Comment: So you ask a questions and answer it within a minute? Why??

Comment: @samayo Because there is no relevant question and answer to the topic on stackoverflow yet. (Atleast I wasn't able to find anything)

Comment: Then you should have wrote it [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) or in [References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) or at least give others 5 minutes to reply

Comment: @samayo self answers are ok. there is even a checkbox to write an answer while you ask a question. this is definitely an accepted practice on Stack Exchange, abiding by the rules™

Comment: Yes, but not within 2 minutes, before anyone gets to take a look or even reply. If you think you have an answer to a questions which you only asked yourself, it doesn't necessarily mean you have to share it here. By that logic, we could all ask and answer every little answer to a every question that are not posted here

Comment: yes, between 2 minutes, as I said, **there is even a checkbox which you can use to answer your question while your are asking it**. you really need to back down from this, it is totally fine to self answer.

Comment: @samayo I am unsure if your trolling or if you really mean that in a serious way. If I think I have an answer to a question that affects PHP and a function of them and there is no entry to find on stackoverflow I will **definetly** post a question and **instantly** answer that, so others can find it and it may be helpful for them. Take one step away from only grinding reputation and instead atleast **try** to see it in a way to be helpful for other users.

Comment: Note that `getStaticVariables()` also includes `static $foo = "bar";`: https://3v4l.org/pf8mb#v560